# Fix error 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Tags: python, string, tuples

I would implement a simple program that tries to guess which word have you chosen among the available ones, based on your hints. This is what I have done so far:

```
print('you have 2 words you can give hints of, Panda, or bucket ')
term = ('china','chinese','bamboo','bear','panda','black','white',
        'black and white','cute','adorable','big','ying and yang')
hint1 =input('Give me a hint   ')
if term in hint1:
    print('I think it is a panda!')
```

Right now I am stuck on the panda part and it raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/edwardandreilucaciu/Documents/guesser.py", line 4, in <module>
    if term in hint1:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: All of these edits have removed important pieces of code each time. As it stands, `term` is undefined.

Comment: @JordanSinger  Look at the (former) slider at the bottom of the code block.  The definition of `term` was pushed off the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed to flip the order of your variables in your `if` statement:

```
print('you have 2 words you can give hints of, Panda, or bucket ')
term = ('china','chinese','bamboo','bear','panda','black','white',
        'black and white','cute','adorable','big','ying and yang')

hint1 =input('Give me a hint ')
if hint1 in term:
    print('I think it is a panda!')
```